# In Python, is there a way to change the block size of an AES cipher?

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto

in pycrypto documentation
http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/

block_size is a variable of AESCipher and set to 16.
Apparently it can't be changed

Am i right?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably there is no way to do this, because AES specifies a block size of 128 bits (16 bytes). Note that the *key size* is different and can vary (128, 192, or 256 bits).

From [Understanding Cryptography, chapter 4.2, Overview of the AES Algorithm](http://wiki.crypto.rub.de/Buch/download/Understanding-Cryptography-Chapter4.pdf):

> The AES cipher is almost identical to the block cipher Rijndael. The
>   Rijndael block and key size vary between 128, 192 and 256 bits.
>   However, the AES standard only calls for a block size of 128 bits.
>   Hence, only Rijndael with a block length of 128 bits is known as the
>   AES algorithm.

If you want a variant that has another block size but is otherwise identical, you should be looking at implementations of Rijndael, not AES.